Power BI RLS data model structure question
I'm trying to implement RLS in Power BI by creating the RLS rule on the DIM_USER table user_email = USERPRINCIPALNAME(). I want the filter to propagate all the way through to the DIM_REPORT table but can't get it to work. Each relationship is set to cross-filter in both directions.
Expected behavior = a user only sees the reports that they have access to given their security group role. Reality = all users see all reports.

